# Flutter Desktop: OCR on cropped image

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, ocr

My code currently fetches a screenshot and crops the image to an area that displays one line of text. I'm trying to use flutter_ocr_sdk package to perform OCR on the image to retrieve the text on the image. Any ideas to what I am doing wrong to achieve this? Below is my code and screenshots:
https://imgur.com/a/4OUGBw7

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_ocr_sdk/mrz_line.dart';
import 'package:flutter_ocr_sdk/mrz_parser.dart';
import 'package:image/image.dart' as img;
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';
import 'package:flutter_ocr_sdk/flutter_ocr_sdk.dart';
import 'package:screen_capturer/screen_capturer.dart';

void main() => runApp(MaterialApp(home: ScreenCalcScreen()));

class ScreenCalcScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const ScreenCalcScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<ScreenCalcScreen> createState() => _ScreenCalcScreenScreenState();
}

class _ScreenCalcScreenScreenState extends State<ScreenCalcScreen> {
  bool _isAccessAllowed = false;
  String _displayedImagePath = '';
  String _displayedText = '';
  CapturedData? _lastCapturedData;
  FlutterOcrSdk _ocrDetector = FlutterOcrSdk();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _init();
  }

  void _init() async {
    _isAccessAllowed = await ScreenCapturer.instance.isAccessAllowed();
    FlutterOcrSdk _mrzDetector = FlutterOcrSdk();
    int? ret = await _mrzDetector.init( "DLS2eyJoYW5kc2hha2VDb2RlIjoiMjAwMDAxLTE2NDk4Mjk3OTI2MzUiLCJvcmdhbml6YXRpb25JRCI6IjIwMDAwMSIsInNlc3Npb25QYXNzd29yZCI6IndTcGR6Vm05WDJrcEQ5YUoifQ==");
    await _mrzDetector.loadModel();
    print(await _mrzDetector.getPlatformVersion());
    if (ret != 0) {
      print("OCR detector initialization failed");
    }
  }

  Future<void> _handleClickCapture(CaptureMode mode) async {
    Directory directory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    String imageName = 'Screenshot-${DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch}.png';
    String imagePath = '${directory.path}/screen_capturer_example/Screenshots/$imageName';
    _lastCapturedData = await ScreenCapturer.instance.capture(
      mode: mode,
      imagePath: imagePath,
      silent: true,
    );

    if (_lastCapturedData != null) {
      final croppedImagePath = await _cropImage(_lastCapturedData!.imagePath!);

      // Perform OCR on the cropped image using flutter_ocr_sdk
      final recognizedText = await _performOCR(croppedImagePath) ?? 'No text found';

      setState(() {
        _displayedText = recognizedText;
        _displayedImagePath = croppedImagePath;
      });
    } else {
      print('User canceled capture');
    }
  }

  Future<String> _cropImage(String imagePath) async {
    final image = img.decodeImage(File(imagePath).readAsBytesSync());
    if (image == null) {
      throw Exception('Failed to load image');
    }

    final croppedImage = img.copyCrop(image, x: 215, y: 205, width: 215, height: 25);

    final croppedImagePath = imagePath.replaceFirst('.png', '_cropped.png');
    File(croppedImagePath).writeAsBytesSync(img.encodePng(croppedImage));

    print(croppedImagePath);
    return croppedImagePath;
  }

  Future<String?> _performOCR(String croppedImagePath) async {
    print("performing OCR");

    try {
      // Recognize text from an image file
      List<List<MrzLine>>? results = await _ocrDetector.recognizeByFile(croppedImagePath);

      String recognizedText = 'No text found'; // Default value
      print(results.runtimeType);
      print(results?.isNotEmpty);
      if (results != null && results.isNotEmpty) {
        // Assuming you have only one line of text
        recognizedText = results[0][0].text;
      }

      return recognizedText;
    } catch (e) {
      print("OCR error: $e");
      return null; // Return null in case of an error
    }
  }





  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Screenshot and OCR Example'),
        ),
        body: Center(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  _handleClickCapture(CaptureMode.screen);
                },
                child: Text('Capture Screenshot'),
              ),
              SizedBox(height: 20),
              if (_displayedImagePath.isNotEmpty)
                Container(
                  margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 20),
                  width: 400,
                  height: 400,
                  child: Image.file(
                    File(_displayedImagePath),
                  ),
                ),
              SizedBox(height: 20),
              if (_displayedText.isNotEmpty)
                Text(
                  'Recognized Text:',
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                ),
              if (_displayedText.isNotEmpty)
                Text(
                  _displayedText,
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16),
                ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```